# React alert message is displaying twice

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I’m trying to display Alert message if API return false. I can do that but for some reason, in the UI I’m getting alert displayed 2x. Also in the dropdown change method, that API should be called and will return maybe has returned value true (If has returned true, the Alert should be hide).

The Alert is called in the child component and the child is called in the parent:

```
//Parent

import React from 'react'
import Header from '../Header';

const Parent = ()  => {
.....
render(
    <Header />
  );
 }
 export default Parent;

 // Child

 import React from 'react'
 import Alert from '@alert-react'
 import Dropdown from '@dropdown-react'

export default class Header extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        defaultMessage: []
    };
this.getData = this.getData.bind(this);
this.onDropdownChange = this.onDropdownChange.bind(this)
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.getData();
}

getData = () => {
    fetch("api")
    .then(response => {
        let test = !response.defaultApiMessage;
        this.setState({
            defaultMessage: test
        })
    })
}
   onDropdownChange = (selectVal) => {
        this.getData();
    }

render() {
    return(
        <Dropdown 
        onChange={onDropdownChange()}
        />
        <div>
        { 
        this.state.defaultMessage && (
        <Alert message="test" />
        )
        }
        </div>
    )
}

}
```

Result: Alert is called twice, one time in Header section and one time in Main section

Answer (score 0):

Move the `onDropdownChange` function out of the`render` function. Update your code like this:

```
//Parent

import React from 'react'
import Header from '../Header';

const Parent = ()  => {
.....
render(
    <Header />
  );
 }
 export default Parent;

 // Child

 import React from 'react'
 import Alert from '@alert-react'
 import Dropdown from '@dropdown-react'

    export default class Header extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            defaultMessage: []
        }
        this.getData = this.getData.bind(this) 
        this.onDropdownChange = this.onDropdownChange.bind(this)
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.getData();
    }

    onDropdownChange(selectVal){
            this.getData();
        }

    getData(){
        fetch("api")
        .then(response => {
            let test = !response.defaultApiMessage;
            this.setState({
                defaultMessage: test
            })
        })
    }

    render() {

        return(
            <Dropdown 
            onChange={this.onDropdownChange}
            />
            <div>
            { 
            this.state.defaultMessage && (
            <Alert message="test" />
            )
            }
            </div>
        )
    }

    }
```

Comment: You should have `onChange={this.onDropdownChange()}` and not `onChange={onDropdownChange()}`. Notice the `this` keyword

Comment: I'm using ESLint and not allow me to add outside the render an arrow function `const onDropdownChange = (selectedValue) => `

Comment: Add `this.getData = this.getData.bind(this)` to the constructor, and change `const getData=()=> {...}` to `getData(){...}` . I have updated my solution,

Comment: Now I'm getting error ` Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined`

Comment: The error you are getting means that the `onDropdownChange` function is not a property of the `Header ` class. Are you sure you've move the `onDropdownChange` function outside the `render` function?

Comment: My bad, remove the `const` keyword from the `onDropdownChange` function. I have updated my answer

Comment: @Iomse yes I have moved out render function

Comment: @Iomse yes I did that because I saw that again I'm getting ESLint error and removed `const`, but without const, is not working again

Comment: I wrote `const onDropdownChange(selectVal){...}` instead of `onDropdownChange(selectVal){}...`. Remove the `const` keyword

Comment: Can you update your post with what you have right now?

Comment: Change `onChange={this.onDropdownChange()}` to `onChange={this.onDropdownChange}` in the render function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207428/discussion-between-lomse-and-alar).

Answer (score 0):

Move `onDropdownChange` from the render function, as its going to get called every time the component is re-rendered.

This can lead to multiple re-renders and is probably the cause for seeing the alert behaviour multiple times.

Comment: I did, it's same issue again

Comment: Is onChange being called from the DropDown as soon as the component mounts?

Comment: Remove the componentDidMount call then. Since this.getData() is being called multiple times. A better way would be to debounce the function in some way, or prevent it from calling onChange when its mounted.

Comment: State is a pain to manage in class based components. I believe Facebook recommends the use of functional components now.